# Implement a SSH client on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, terminal

Have anyone known of an open source project to implement SSH client on iPHone ?
I actually need a terminal emulation to run a console application I have,  I dont even need to get out of my sandbox. But Havent find any terminal emulation that doesnt infringe apple rules. (-MobileTerminal- just works on jailbroken, and does run my console app) and AFAIK its not possible to implement an Appstore valid version of it because of its forkpty() implementation.

still I see lots of SSH clients (terminal like) on the AppStore that send a recieve data. So there has to be a way to emulate a terminal/console thing on iPhone... thats what I need, but I see no one giving out some source code.

Comment: Look at the xterm source code: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/, the basis for most terminal implementations.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: xterm is very tightly bound to Xlib and being an X11 terminal emulator.
If you want a properly abstracted terminal emulation library that can be attached to whatever rendering system you want and embedded in a phone, you might consider instead my libvterm; https://launchpad.net/libvterm

Comment: @LeoNerd looks likes a good library to implement in Xcode for iPhone. But do u have any Documentation or manual on how to use it ? Thanks

Comment: @Electrum: Not a great deal yet as it's still somewhat in progress. Between a good reading of the .h file and the reference implementation of https://launchpad.net/pangoterm there should be enough to start with. If people want to start looking at it I can start thinking about writing some...

Comment: @LeoNerd I looked at the code from Pangoterm and I see it uses forkpty(). This function is not allowed to be used in iOS/iPhone because it infringe Apple rules getting access to system. So probably your library wont help me. :(

Comment: @Electrum: forkpty() is what is used to be a /real/ local terminal emulator on a real UNIX machine. It wouldn't be required for writing an SSH terminal client on a phone. Observe carefully: libvterm contains the actual abstract terminal implementation, pangoterm is the GTK/Pango/Cairo container for it to host it on my Linux desktop. Other hosting environments might be different.

Comment: Did you ever find a terminal emulator for iOS? I'm looking for a class that emulates DOS, curses or Windows Console.

Comment: Sorry havent find anything yet :(

Answer (score 1):

A quick google of mine shows this as a possible option:
http://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/

It's in the Cydia store as well, and should give you general direction. If you want to look at the final implementation, I recommend Panic Software's Prompt - http://www.panic.com/prompt/support.html

Comment: Yes that what Im referencing in my post. MobileTerminal is an open source Terminal emulator that only works on Cydia, that means Jailbroken phones. Panic Prompt App is great and its AppStore valid. Would be great an open source project like that one; that doesnt need jailbreak to work. What I need is just the terminal interface to run my own binary. I dont need any access to restricted folders or stuff. But Im surprised how there are bunch of SSH clients in official appstore but no references anywhere for snippet codes to get started on console interfaces.

Comment: Not sure I follow - the console application runs on a remote server? Or within the console itself on the device?

Comment: the console app runs within the iPhone. I actually dont need to make a ssh connection. I need to run a console app in the iphone, I have the code for that console app written in C.. it actually compiles in Xcode for the iPhone.. but this code needs a Terminal interface to show and read stuff. (it is a console app to connect to a router and send/recieve data, commands for configuration, etc..). Thats the thing.. I still need a terminal emulator, like Panic Prompt which is excelent.. I need just that, the interface but to interact with local console app.

Comment: Hi @omarojo , i am also working with same concept and access sever emulator in my iPod.can you give me some guidelines or may source code regarding this.

Comment: Sorry @SumitGarg I never found a way to do it, so I killed the project.